# Configuration error in Sitecore Website deployed to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, sitecore, sitecore8

I have deployed my Sitecore website to Azure using Visual Studio. Now when browsing the site its giving me Configuration error.

---

Server Error in '/' Application.
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

---

Is there any config setting needs to be done for Sitecore webconfig? Its not giving any other error details so that I can check.

How to resolve please suggest.

Comment: The last line of the message (The current custom error settings...) is telling that some setting is blocking further details from displaying. In your web.config set <customErrors mode="Off" /> so that error details are displayed.

Comment: customErrors mode in web.cong file is already set to "Off"

Comment: can you rdp to system - if yes try running using localhost

Comment: No, remote connect option not comes with website. Is tehre any other way to rdp?

Comment: you can use connect button in azure portal to rdp (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-log-on-windows-server/)

Comment: Connect button comes with Virtual machine and cloud serviced but not with Webapps

Comment: you can use remote debugging if possible.

Comment: My bad! If you can ftp into your folder (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/waws/archive/2014/02/20/how-to-ftp-into-a-waws-site.aspx) - there may be a logFiles folder created. There may be an xml with additional details in it

Answer (score 0):

You may use **Remote Debugging** (which can be enabled in Azure Portal) to set breakpoints and see exceptions. If you have linked your Azure account in Visual Studio 2013 or 2015, it is super easy to just right click your web app and choose *Attach Debugger*.

More information: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/#remotedebug

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the .NET Framework version for your application pool in IIS is set to v4.0.